# Heading not aligned properly relative to table

Tags: html, css

I have a 4x3 HTML table, which houses icons .. There is a heading above this table .. If you look closely, you'll notice that the heading is slightly to the right, relative to the vertical center of the table ..

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/Mufvw/

**Note:** The code I've mentioned here is part of a larger footer section of a webpage. So don't make too drastic changes, because then the solution might be incompatible with the original page.

**Here is the original page where this appears (in the footer):** http://bit.ly/12hny0I

HTML Code:

```
<body bgcolor="#000000">

<div class="footer_wrap">
    <div class="footer_bg">


        <div class="blog_Sec">
            <!--blog_nav-->

            <div class="partners1" style="margin-top:-10px">
                <span class="heading">Payment Partners</span> 

                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td align="center">
                                <a class="tiptip" href=
                                "http://www.moneybookers.com" target="_blank"
                                title="Moneybookers/Skrill"><img onmouseout=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/moneybookers.png'"
                                onmouseover=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/moneybookers.png'"
                                src=
                                "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/moneybookers.png"></a>
                            </td>

                            <td align="center">
                                <a class="tiptip" href=
                                "http://www.2checkout.com" target="_blank"
                                title="2Checkout"><img onmouseout=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/2checkout.png'"
                                onmouseover=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/2checkout.png'"
                                src=
                                "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/2checkout.png"></a>
                            </td>

                            <td align="center" style="padding-bottom: 4px;">
                                <a class="tiptip" href="http://www.visa.com"
                                target="_blank" title="VISA"><img onmouseout=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/visa.png'"
                                onmouseover=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/visa.png'"
                                src=
                                "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/visa.png"></a>
                            </td>

                            <td align="center">
                                <a class="tiptip" href=
                                "http://www.mastercard.com" target="_blank"
                                title="MasterCard"><img onmouseout=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/mastercard.png'"
                                onmouseover=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/mastercard.png'"
                                src=
                                "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/mastercard.png"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr align="center">
                            <td align="center">
                                <a class="tiptip" href=
                                "http://www.ubldirect.com/corporate/bankingservices/omni/home.aspx"
                                target="_blank" title=
                                "UBL Omni"><img onmouseout=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/omni.png'"
                                onmouseover=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/omni.png'"
                                src=
                                "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/omni.png"></a>
                            </td>

                            <td align="center">
                                <a class="tiptip" href=
                                "http://www.easypaisa.com.pk" target="_blank"
                                title="EasyPaisa"><img onmouseout=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/easypaisa.png'"
                                onmouseover=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/easypaisa.png'"
                                src=
                                "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/easypaisa.png"></a>
                            </td>

                            <td align="center">
                                <a class="tiptip" href="http://www.hbl.com"
                                target="_blank" title=
                                "Habib Bank Limited"><img onmouseout=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/hbl.png'"
                                onmouseover=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/hbl.png'"
                                src=
                                "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/hbl.png"></a>
                            </td>

                            <td align="center">
                                <a class="tiptip" href=
                                "http://www.standardchartered.com.pk" target=
                                "_blank" title=
                                "Standard Chartered Pakistan"><img onmouseout=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/scb.png'"
                                onmouseover=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/scb.png'"
                                src=
                                "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/scb.png"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr align="center">
                            <td align="center">
                                <a class="tiptip" href="http://www.abl.com"
                                target="_blank" title=
                                "Allied Bank Limited"><img onmouseout=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/abl.png'"
                                onmouseover=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/abl.png'"
                                src=
                                "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/abl.png"></a>
                            </td>

                            <td align="center">
                                <a class="tiptip" href=
                                "http://www.faysalbank.com" target="_blank"
                                title="Faysal Bank Limited"><img onmouseout=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/faysal.png'"
                                onmouseover=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/faysal.png'"
                                src=
                                "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/faysal.png"></a>
                            </td>

                            <td align="center">
                                <a class="tiptip" href=
                                "http://www.bankalfalah.com" target="_blank"
                                title="Bank Alfalah"><img onmouseout=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/alfalah.png'"
                                onmouseover=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/alfalah.png'"
                                src=
                                "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/alfalah.png"></a>
                            </td>

                            <td align="center">
                                <a class="tiptip" href=
                                "http://www.ubldirect.com" target="_blank"
                                title="United Bank Limited"><img onmouseout=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/ubl.png'"
                                onmouseover=
                                "this.src='http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/ubl.png'"
                                src=
                                "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/normal/ubl.png"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div style="display:none">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src=
                        "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/moneybookers.png"></td>

                        <td><img src=
                        "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/2checkout.png"></td>

                        <td><img src=
                        "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/visa.png"></td>

                        <td><img src=
                        "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/mastercard.png"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><img src=
                        "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/omni.png"></td>

                        <td><img src=
                        "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/easypaisa.png"></td>

                        <td><img src=
                        "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/hbl.png"></td>

                        <td><img src=
                        "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/scb.png"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><img src=
                        "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/abl.png"></td>

                        <td><img src=
                        "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/faysal.png"></td>

                        <td><img src=
                        "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/alfalah.png"></td>

                        <td><img src=
                        "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/paymenticons/hover/ubl.png"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table><img src="http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/socialicons/hover/f_logo.png">
            <img src="http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/socialicons/hover/t_logo.png"> <img src=
            "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/socialicons/hover/g_logo.png"> <img src=
            "http://173.254.28.69/~bluraysp/image/data/socialicons/hover/r_logo.png"></div>


        </div><!--blog_Sec End-->


    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: It's funny how you've tagged this question to html5 and css3...

Comment: I was actually on the phone when I was tagging, so I guess I messed up a little :) ..

Comment: I think if you applied the same width to the and the elements it would solve it because the .heading element is currently larger than the table, hence we its not quite centered correctly.

Comment: Pattle, I don't fully understand your statement .. How are you concluding that the heading element is larger than the table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class 'tableDisplay' to both elements and then change the display type:

```
.tableDisplay{ display: table-row; }
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mufvw/3/

Comment: It does correct the problem, but if I try adding that additional CSS rule to the main webpage ([link](http://bit.ly/12hny0I)), it messes up the other headings in the footer ..

Comment: @Ahmad I wrote my example for the content you had with your question. To solve this, simply apply a class to the heading and the table and then apply the CSS rule to them. Check the updated fiddle.